# Problems with mysqli_real_escape_string, inserting string works fine

Tags: php, sql, database

Trying to insert the Cookievalue into my database.
Like this it's not Working (=no new data in the db)

```
$con = mysqli_connect("", "root", "", "db");
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['firstname']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (firstname) VALUES ($firstname)";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

but if I insert the VALUE like 'hello' it works fine.

Comment: Dont use it, its not safe! Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Please add the issue you are facing in the question.

Comment: try it $sql = "INSERT INTO table (firstname) VALUES ('$firstname')";

Comment: @RiggsFolly why is it not safe?
P.S.: Im a new coder

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: And thank you @Rahul Shrivastava, it really worked ;)